# Lecture notes about numerical solutions for 2 dimensional PDE with python/matlab codes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I am wondering is there any book focus on the numerical solutions to the 2-dimensional PDE with some python or MATLAB codes?

Comment: I strongly advise "Numerical Methods in Finance and Economics, A Matlab based introduction" Paolo Brandimarte (Wiley) 2002 : Don't be afraid by the "Finance and Economics": a good part of the book is faily general.

Comment: Hans Langtangen has some good books using python and with code; see [here](http://hplgit.github.io/prog4comp/doc/pub/p4c_Python.pdf) for an introduction to numerical methods, [here](https://hplgit.github.io/fdm-book/doc/pub/book/pdf/fdm-book-4print.pdf) for finite difference methods including 2D problems and [here](https://hplgit.github.io/fem-book/doc/pub/book/pdf/fem-book-4print.pdf) for finite element methods including 2D problems.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thank you for the answer!!!

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This very much depends on what PDEs you want to study. Can you specify any specific types you are interested in? Especially at the numerical level, things get very specific to e.g., hyperbolic vs. elliptic elliptic equations.